# Extracting resource details from a module to use in another module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a two Terraform modules, one creates a log analytics workspace, and the other creates a virtual network.

I am trying to configure the virtual network module to send the virtual network diagnostics to the log analytics workspace created in the other module, however I am unsure on how to do this.

When writing the resource block to configure diagnostics settings, it prompts for the **log_analytics_workspace_id**, however the virtual network module doesn't know what it is, how do I get that information from another module?

Thank you

**Root Template**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }
  required_version = "> 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "log_analytics" {
  source = "./modules/log_analytics"
}

module "vnet" {
  source = "./modules/vnet"

  vnet_depends_on         = [module.log_analytics]
  log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics.log_analytics_workspace_id.id
}
```

**Log Analytics Module**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }
  required_version = "> 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# RESOURCE GROUP DEPLOYMENT
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_log_analytics_workspace" {
  name     = var.rg_log_analytics.name
  location = var.rg_log_analytics.location
  tags     = var.rg_tags
}

# LOG ANALYTICS DEPLOYMENT
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analytics_workspace" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.rg_log_analytics_workspace]
  name                = var.log_analytics.name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_log_analytics.name
  location            = var.rg_log_analytics.location
  retention_in_days   = var.log_analytics.retention
}
```

**Log Analytics Module Output**

```
output "log_analytics_workspace_id" {
    value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace.id
}
```

**Virtual Network Module**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }
  required_version = "> 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "vnet_depends_on" {
  type = any
  default = []
}

variable "log_analytics_workspace_id" {
  type = any
  default = []
}

# RESOURCE GROUP DEPLOYMENT
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_networking" {
  name     = var.rg_networking.name
  location = var.rg_networking.location
  tags     = var.rg_tags
}

# VIRTUAL NETWORK DEPLOYMENT
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg_networking,var.vnet_depends_on]
  name                = var.vnet.config.name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_networking.name
  location            = var.rg_networking.location
  address_space       = var.vnet.config.address_space
  dns_servers         = var.vnet.config.dns_servers
}

# SUBNETS DEPLOYMENT
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
  for_each             = var.subnets
  resource_group_name  = var.rg_networking.name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet.config.name
  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "vnet_peering" {
  depends_on                   = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
  for_each                     = var.vnet_peering
  name                         = each.value.name
  resource_group_name          = each.value.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name         = each.value.virtual_network_name
  remote_virtual_network_id    = each.value.remote_virtual_network_id
  allow_virtual_network_access = each.value.allow_virtual_network_access
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = each.value.allow_forwarded_traffic
  allow_gateway_transit        = each.value.allow_gateway_transit
  use_remote_gateways          = each.value.use_remote_gateways
}

# CONFIGURE VNET DIAGNOSTIC SETTINGS
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "vnet_diagnostics" {
  name = "Diagnostic Settings"
  target_resource_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
  log {
    category = "VmprotectionAlerts"
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code to the question. The easy answer is: you have to define outputs in the log analytics workspace module.

Comment: @markoE, I'm new to stock overflow, trying to figure out how to add the code in at the moment. My log analytics workspace module has an output file that will produce the workspace ID once created. I just don't know how to use that output in the vnet module?

Comment: Sorry, can't add an answer without seeing the code. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @MarkoE, sorted, I've added the three main templates with everything I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, you said you have defined the output in the log analytics workspace module? There is no code for that. If you haven't defined it, then I can provide the answer.

Comment: @markoE, the output code is in the log analytics output file, I've added that to this thread now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you understand how to reference the module outputs [1]. Module outputs are referenced like this:

```
module.<MODULE NAME>.<OUTPUT NAME>
```

The solution should be pretty easy. Instead of using this as output reference:

```
  log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics.log_analytics_workspace_id.id
```

You need only this:

```
log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics.log_analytics_workspace_id
```

Additionally, when you are making an implicit reference (which you do when referencing a module output), you do not need the explicit reference that you have created with `depends_on` meta-argument. The code would then look like this:

```
module "vnet" {
  source = "./modules/vnet"

  log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics.log_analytics_workspace_id
}
```

The same applies for the virtual network module code as you can use implicit references to resources instead of variables, but that is a different discussion.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#child-module-outputs

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `id` reference from the vNet module, as only the output name is required:

```
module "vnet" {
  source = "./modules/vnet"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics.log_analytics_workspace_id
}
```

I've removed the `depends_on` as well as it's not needed here, there's an implicit dependency already defined.